# How can I change a variable in a .txt template, if I have more than 5000 different values for this variable in an excel table?

Tags: excel, pandas, templates, variables, text-files

I have an excel table with a column called 'interface', and what I want to do is a code that pull each interface value : Port-channel47, Port-channel46,etc... and put it in my .txt template replacing the {interface} part that i have in my txt template.

[image: excel table]

the value I want to change in the .txt template is  "{interface}"

[image: txt template;]

I tried this code:

[image: code]

but I get lost when i want to pull the data.

Anyone can help me? thank you so much in advance

Comment: Screenshots of code don't really work here... please [edit] your question with the code as text.

Comment: You can find all unique values in the column by using: df.Interface.unique()
You should only open the file once and then write several lines to it. Here you open the file for each interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use string template:

```
from string import Template

with open('template.txt') as fp:
    template = Template(fp.read())

for interface, group in df.groupby('Interface'):
    file_name = interface.replace('/', '_') + '_output.txt'
    with open(file_name, 'w') as fp:
        content = template.substitute(interface=interface)
        fp.write(content)
```

When you iterate over a `DataFrameGroupBy` object, it returns a *2-tuple* containing the key of the group, and all rows matching that key.

A second thing to worry about is that `/` is not a valid path under most OSes I know so you must replace it with some other character (I chose a `_`).

Comment: Hello @Mike ,Firstly thanks so much for your help; At the beggining it didnt change anything inside my txt-file but then i added the '$' in my  'interface' string so it works now; Now i am trying to create a txt-file for each value of interface, because I need 1 file for each NE value in my excel